# Get Selected Items of listview syncfusion

Tags: javascript, listview, syncfusion

i want to show the selected items of listview in a grid. all selected items should show on the home page. but i cant find a way to do so. i have attached the js file code and screenshot of the popup

```js
var subItemsLoaded = false,
    SubItemSelectionModalId = '#subItemSelectionModal';
listViewHeight = 400,
subItemClicked = 0;

$(SubItemSelectionModalId).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    if (
        (window.selections.assetTemplate.id != null &&
        window.selections.assetTemplate.id != 0)) {
        $(SubItemSelectionModalId + ' .modal-body').ejWaitingPopup({
            showOnInit: true
        });
        $(SubItemSelectionModalId + ' .listViewItems').ejListView({
            "height": 400,
            "loadComplete": function () {
                repositionSearchBoxFor(SubItemSelectionModalId);
                var obj = $(SubItemSelectionModalId + ' .modal-body').data("ejWaitingPopup");
                console.log("12345.5");
                obj.hide();
                console.log("123456");
            },

            "mouseUp": function (e) {
            },
            "enableAjax": true,
            "enableCheckMark": true,
            "enableFiltering": true,
            "dataSource": ej.DataManager({
                "url": "/Shared",
                "cachingPageSize": 0,
                "timeTillExpiration": 0
            }),
            "query": ej.Query().from("GetSubItems").addParams("assetTemplateId", window.selections.assetTemplate.id).addParams("assetTemplateVariantId", window.selections.assetTemplateVariant.id),
            "fieldSettings": {
                "text": "SubItemName",
                "id": "SubItemId"
            }
        });
    }
});

$(SubItemSelectionModalId).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    var listViewItems = $(SubItemSelectionModalId + ' .listViewItems');
    if (listViewItems.find('ul').length > 0) {
        var selections = $(SubItemSelectionModalId + ' .listViewItems').ejListView("getCheckedItems");
        if (selections.length > 0) {
            $('#selectedSubItems').html(selections.join(' , ')).removeClass('hidden');
        }
    }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr3TZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to show the selected items of the Listview in a Grid. For this, you have to use the mouseUp event of the Listview to take the selected items of the list and then give these selected items as the dataSource for the Grid control.

Also in order to get the ID of the selected list, you have to get the ID attribute and take its ID and bind the ID field as one of the columns of the Grid control. This way, you can get the ID of a particular list in a Listview and then bind it to the Grid.

We have also prepared a sample for your reference: http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/prahqy2i

Regards,
Arun P.